# Docusign: composite templates with tabs

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

How do I specify prefilled fields with composite templates when creating an envelope.

I tried including the tabs information in the `inlineTemplate.recipients.signers[0].tabs`, but I get an error that `System.String cannot be cast to API_REST.Models.v2.tabs`.

If I include information as a template role in `templateRoles`, it is ignored. The documentation is light on information about how to do this. It seems like the prefill data should be specified in the inline template.

Other open questions I have include what does the `recipientId` do. What is the `clientUserId`used for? We currently set `clientUserId` to the same value for all signers. I see it's used when signer requests a signature. Should it be unique to every signer for some reason?

It also looks like a single composite template overlays the server and inline templates on top of each other. What's the use case for having multiple server templates or multiple inline templates in a single composite template?

Are there plans to improve the documentation to describe how to use composite templates for various purposes?

Signer/template role:

```
{
  "clientUserId": "clientUserId",
  "email": "first+last@email.com",
  "name": "First Last",
  "roleName": "role1",
  "tabs": {
    "textTabs": [
      {
        "locked": true,
        "tabLabel": "\\*FieldName",
        "value": "prefillValue"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Example request:

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "clientUserId": "clientUserId",
                "email": "first+last@email.com",
                "name": "First Last",
                "recipientId": 1,
                "roleName": "role1",
                "tabs": {
                  "textTabs": [{"tabLabel": "label", "value": "val"}]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": 1
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": 1,
          "templateId": "templateId1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "clientUserId": "clientUserId",
                "email": "first+last@better.com",
                "name": "First Last",
                "recipientId": 1,
                "roleName": "role1",
                "tabs": {
                  "textTabs": [{"tabLabel": "label", "value": "val"}]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": 2
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": 2,
          "templateId": "templateId2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Email subject",
  "status": "sent",
  "templateId": null,
  "templateRoles": null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information on sending an envelope from a server template can be found [here.](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____39)

RecipientID is used by the tab element to indicate which recipient is to sign the Document while the clientuserID specifies if the user is [remote or embedded](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) and it is recommended it be unique per signer (but not required).

I'd also suggest reading [this page](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/templates) about composite templates, hopefully the concept will make a bit more sense but I am with you that the lack of documentation on composite templates can be troublesome.

Unfortunately, I don't have a sample with tab data included, but adding the tab section under each recipient from my sample below should work with no issues.

```
{
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign Comp Test 1",
  "emailBlurb": "Example - Composite Templates",
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "templateId1"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "testsigner123@gmail.com",
                "name": "Test Tester",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "Signer 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "templateId": "templateId2"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "testsigner123@gmail.com",
                "name": "Test Tester",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "Signer 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {    
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "3",
          "templateId": "templateId3"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "testsigner123@gmail.com",
                "name": "Test Tester",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "Signer 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've read through those doc pages before. I am still unclear on where to specify the tab information. I tried including it at the root level `templateRoles`, under `inlineTemplates[0]`, under `inlineTemplates[0].recipients`, and under `inlineTemplates[0].recipients.singers[0]`. All but the last configuration is ignored. The last one (where it seems like it should go) returns an error.

Comment: I was able to add tabs under the signer. I was running into an encoding problem with the docusign client I am using. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I just read through my post and realized I did say add the tab info under "Recipients" when it should be further under that with "Signers." My apologies!!!

Comment: The documentation isn't great around this area. I was trying to add the tab data to the template roles. Shifting it to the recipient of the inline template worked for me. Thanks.